# Is there a book about motivation behind the choices in material design?

Tags: resource-recommendations, google-material-design

As in the title, has there been a book released about motivation behind the choices in [material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)? I would like to read why and how some choices were made.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a book or more in depth explanation behind each design decision in material design.

It is based on [three principles](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-principles) and all other decisions (arguably) follow those rules:

1. Material is the metaphor
2. Be bold, graphic, intentional
3. Provide meaning with motion